# How to make use of delegated service account (that has already gone through obtaining a JWT) to modify domain-wide emails?

Tags: javascript, gmail, google-oauth

What I am presently attempting to achieve is to write a tool in order to update all email addresses on my domain with a given customized Signature that would have its details updated based on a csv file that it is currently drawing from. What I'm hoping to eventually do is to actually get all users under the domain, get each user's details from the Directory, then update those details without actually needing a CSV file.

For now, though, a more fundamental issue comes up, even after I have prepared an access token after going through the entire convoluted flow that is creating a JWT and obtaining an access token through sending a POST request to the OAuth2 endpoint (process not shown, but it's saved as accessToken below), how am I to apply that access token made using the credentials of my pre-prepared service account in order to actually get to modify the appropriate signature of the email I am currently editing? (email seen below as CURRENTEMAIL)

```
function updateSignature(contentToUpdate){
        gapi.auth.setToken(accessToken);
        // https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/patch 
        return gapi.client.gmail.users.settings.sendAs.patch ({
            //"auth": accessToken, 
            "userId": 'me',
            "sendAsEmail": CURRENTEMAIL,
            "resource": {
              "signature": contentToUpdate
            }
          }).then(function(response) {

                      console.log("Response", response);
                    },
        function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); 
        });
    }
```

So far, I've gotten idpiframe_initialization_failed errors when attempting to use the service account's client id during initialization, so I believe that's not how to go about using the key, and using the method above has only told me that I need to make any emails that are not my presently-logged-in email (i.e. I am joey@mydomain.com while my target modified email is testaccount@mydomain.com) one of my aliases instead, which doesn't make any sense in the long run. Does anyone know any other means of dealing with this problem?

I've also tried changing the user ID to that of the service account email, but it has only resulted in execute errors where it states that the delegation was denied.

```
(index):400 Execute error 
{result: {…}, body: "{↵ "error": {↵  "errors": [↵   {↵    "domain": "gl…: "Delegation denied for (redacted)"↵ }↵}↵", headers: {…}, status: 403, statusText: null}
body: "{↵ "error": {↵  "errors": [↵   {↵    "domain": "global",↵    "reason": "forbidden",↵    "message": "Delegation denied for (redacted)"↵   }↵  ],↵  "code": 403,↵  "message": "Delegation denied for (redacted)"↵ }↵}↵"
headers: {date: "Wed, 03 Apr 2019 06:01:10 GMT", content-encoding: "gzip", server: "GSE", content-type: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", vary: "Origin, X-Origin", …}
result: {error: {…}}
status: 403
statusText: null
__proto__: Object
```

I've been researching on this topic for the past few days and this is the only method that has been documented by any means, but it only affects aliases the gmail account that I am presently logged in as, (i.e. if I was to log in as joey@mydomain.com and modify the signature of testaccount@mydomain.com while it is listed as an alias of joey@mydomain.com, the updated signature is reflected there, but not when I actually log in as testaccount@mydomain.com)

Am I using the access token wrong, or what am I supposed to do otherwise?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this. Apparently, the best way to go about ignoring the various different -limited- language options is to just perform HTTP requests using jquery.

This is especially useful given that I'm not presently using Node, and Python doesn't really serve my purposes given that it's been semi-established that I'll need to work with the HTML file that contains the custom signature in the first place.

In any case, I solved this via sending a PATCH request to

```
[insert google endpoint here]?access_token=[insert access token obtained via JWT flow]
```

Makes sense, since all these language-specific APIs are basically just doing http requests in the background for us anyway.

Hope this helps anyone else that might be running into the same issue.